# If + adjective or adjective phrase

Tags: phrases, adjectives, conditional-constructions

I notice lots of sentences use *if* directly followed by an adjective or an adjective phrase, for example:

> If necessary, please import more of these types of goods.
>
> If a little taller, he could reach to the book on the bookshelf.

This appears to be one of the places where English lets you omit words and consider them to be "understood". However, all grammars about *if* I googled are talking about conditional clauses; none is talking about *if* + phrase.

Can anyone explain the general rules of *if* + adjective or adjective phrases?

Comment: Maybe search for *"reducible clauses"*, and for *"verbless clauses".* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's another instance of elliptical structure. It's not that the *if-clauses* you demonstrated in your example sentences are not conditional. They are, but some words are left out - **elliptical structure**.

Sometimes we can leave out **subject + verb** after the conjunction *if*. When it's expanded it forms the familiar conditional clause structure.

> ***If in doubt***, ask for help. [ = *If you are in doubt*, ask for help. (Here *if-clause* is also a conditional clause)]
>
> ***If necessary***, please import more of these types of goods. [ = *If it's necessary*, please import more of these type of goods.]
>
> ***If a little taller***, he could reach to the book on the bookshelf. [ = *If he was a little taller*, he could reach to the book on the bookshelf.]